# why does razor skip an attribute if the value is null

Tags: razor

I found it strange that Razor would actually not generating the attribute tag if the value is `@null`.

```
<div class="@null"></div>
```

would be generated as `<div></div>`

but

```
<div class=""></div>
```

would be generated as `<div class=""></div>`

I know that calling `.ToString` on nullable fields will fix this issue, but why is this happening?

Comment: Its as a result of a feature called conditional attributes introduced in Razor-2.0. Refer [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/201/cleaner-conditional-html-attributes-in-razor-web-pages) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing. Presumably they try to produce more efficient output (small HTML) where possible. No point flooding the HTML with blank attributes.

That is a problem sometimes when you actually want a valid blank attribute, like "selected", with no value.